# The code i have written doesnt show results on input percentage

Tags: javascript

Hi im trying to calculate the percentage of 2 inputs but its not showing results can anyone tell me whats the problem

```js
var Shots = document.getElementById("shots").value;
var Makes = document.getElementById("makes").value;

var results = (Makes / Shots) * 100;

function perqindja() {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = results;
};
```

```html
<h2>Calculate your shots</h2>
<p>Type the number of shots taken:</p>
<input type="number" name="Shots" id="shots">
<p>Type the number of shots made:</p>           
<input type="number" name="Makes" id="makes">
<button onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>
<p>The shot percentage:<span id="answer"></span></p>
```

Comment: you need to set the variables inside the function. You're calculating the percentage when the page is first loaded, before the user enters anything into the inputs.

Comment: What parts if your code are actually within the `calculate` function?

Comment: can u give me an example im new to js so i need some help

Comment: or can yall suggest me a better code and "perqindja is basiclly the calculate function

Comment: Perhaps it'd be best to learn some basic JS in a structured way. I recommend [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) (free).

Comment: The code you posted is not runnable as the `Calculate` method isn't defined. There are too many assumptions that would need to be made for someone else to make it runnable. Please update the code in your question to be runnable and accurately show the issue you're describing.

Comment: It won't create an error, but it's customary to only name variables uppercase when they are classes/constructors.

Comment: @code Please don't recommend w3schools.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the variable inside the function so that it could store the `input` value after user click the button. Also, you doesn't define the `Calculate()`. I remove the `perqindja()`  since I don't find it user in the code.

```js
function Calculate() {
        var Shots = document.getElementById("shots").value;
var Makes = document.getElementById("makes").value;

var results = (Makes / Shots) * 100;

    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = results;
};
```

```html
<p>Type the number of shots taken:</p>
<input type="number" name="Shots" id="shots">
<p>Type the number of shots made:</p>           
<input type="number" name="Makes" id="makes">
<button onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>
<p>The shot percentage:<span id="answer"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that the function Calculate is not defined.
By the way, in javascript it is a good practice to give function lower case names.
Second, you need to pass values to the calculate function.

Everything should work once you fix these 2 issues.

Comment: i did that but it didnt work or do i have to create another function like calculate and put it inside this funcion

Comment: if you did that, you would not be getting the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Calculate is not defined"

Answer (score -1):

Your functions name is ‘perqindja()’ but you try to call ‘ Calculate()’ function on click in your html